# Where do hi-pot multipliers come from?

Tags: capacitor, standard, ul, hipot, mlcc

I am researching AC vs. DC hi-pot testing.

According to UL 508 and IEEE 421.3, a hi-pot test should, among other things, subject the unit under test to *1000 volts plus twice the rated voltage of the equipment for industrial control equipment rated 51 – 600 volts*, for 1 minute at 60 Hz.

However, I have repeatedly seen references to multipliers that permit a manufacturer to hi-pot test a product at some multiple of the above calculation for a shorter or longer amount of time. For example, in [this article](http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/what-is-hipot-testing-dielectric-strength-test), the author states, "A typical rule of thumb is 110 to 120% of 2U + 1000 V for 1–2 seconds."

**What standard, if any, do these multipliers appear in? Or is this just an easy way to test a preliminary design to see if you're in the neighborhood, and not ever used for final testing?**

Related question: I have read that Y caps can be removed for hi-pot tests (since the purpose is to test insulation suitability, not component ratings), but again I have not seen this spelled out in a standard. In which standard, if any, is this called out?

Comment: These 'standards' branch out into more specific standards, such as UL1449 3rd and 4th edition, for surge protection devices (SPD). Read my answer to "How did this capacitor survive having a nail driven through it?" The standards can vary based on product type. Medical standards are the toughest.

Comment: The link is:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357025/how-did-this-capacitor-survive-having-a-nail-driven-through-it/357142#357142