# Is this optocoupler front-end safe?

Tags: opto-isolator, transient, tvs

This is a follow-up to [Is this line detector safe?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397137/is-this-line-detector-safe)

I'm re-designing the front-end based on some great feedback from the community. I've decided to move to the following topology:

[image: diagram]

- The phase of the source is set to 90º to model the worst case where a user closes a switch at the top of the line curve; in this case the caps would not yet be charged and R1 + R2 would have to absorb all surge energy
- The surge current would be \$168.6 \text{V} / 1.6 \text{k} \Omega / 2 \approx ~ 53 \text{mA} \ll 150 \text{mA}\$, so the opto would be fine
- During surge, the TVS would still not conduct, because
  \$(168.6\text{V}/2)+1.1\text{V}=85.4\text{V}\$, which is smaller than Vbrmin=86.5V
- During surge, each resistor would see a peak power of ~4.5W. If I use the 
  [CF14JT1K60](https://www.seielect.com/Catalog/SEI-CF_CFM.pdf), based on its pulse derating curve, it would support 4W for ~0.1s, or 50W for ~1ms. Since we have 4W for less than 1ms, we should be quite OK.
- D2 is shown disconnected - in reality it would be connected but I wanted to simulate the circuit as if the protection zener never quite conducts under typical operation. I intended for it to only conduct if there's a transient above the usual line voltage.
- R1 absorbs energy in the event of a transient spike if D2 conducts.
- C1 and C2 are chosen to relieve the burden on R1 and R2 so that their typical non-surge power dissipation is small, and decrease typical current to the opto while still keeping it on. The intent is to provide about 10mApk to the opto. At 60Hz, the total impedance is about

\$2 \left( 1.6\text{k}\Omega + \frac 1 {2\pi j \cdot 60 \text{Hz} \cdot 300 \text{nF}} \right)
\approx 18.0 \text{k}\Omega \angle -79.4º
\$

which allows ~9.4mApk.

- This equates to ~6.7mA RMS; the resistors each then dissipate about 53mW RMS of power each. This is well below the 250mW for which they're rated.

## Transient Simulation

Voltages:

[image: voltages sim]

Current:

[image: current sim]

Resistor peak power:

[image: power sim]

Have I missed anything? Is my method sound?

Comment: Are you expecting this circuit to provide zero crossing information or is it simply to detect that AC is present?

Comment: @JackCreasy the latter, although I haven't shown the second half.

Comment: OK, if you are looking for power failure signals, you should be detecting the peak of each half sine. This way you can detect both brownout and power loss. Most reasonably highly loaded power supplies may have holdup times in the 16 - 300mS range so depending on what you need to do on power loss the timing may be quite critical.

Comment: @JackCreasey interesting - but I'm not looking for power failure, per se, simply the presence of any voltage on this particular mains line.

Comment: Curious, did you build this circuit? Is it working as you expected? I ask because I am endeavoring to do the same thing.

Comment: @Alex it worked quite well but it was never tested for surge.

Comment: @Reinderien just curious why didn't you use TVS Varistor like https://www.newark.com/bourns/mov-20d201k/varistor-200v-130vac-170vdc-20mm/dp/76T0330 instead of the one in a diode pack? they are commonplace in surge protectors. also, is this the final schematic? if you made any modifications please let me know it would be much appreciated!

Comment: _why didn't you use TVS Varistor_ - I probably don't have a good reason other than 'unfamiliarity with this family of circuits'. _is this the final schematic?_ - Ish, but it's not complete. I'll email you the paper I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed nothing important. I did this most every month for 15 years at a surge manufacture plant. While most people might cut corners and have a single RC based reactive power supply it is wise to double up on R and C at times, especially if Vin is prone to surges. Two 3 watt resistors spread the heat and generally had a breakdown voltage of 400 volts, so 2 in series made it 800 volts, with a little safety margin.

Also R dissipates the real current as heat, so even for 120 VAC we used 2 18K 3W resistors in series with an AC type optocoupler. For 600 VAC (Canadian products) we used 2 47K 3W resistors, always the flame-proof type. We only used capacitors (X2) when we needed actual power from one or more phases. It was no more than 60mA with a range of 50mA to 70mA, so capacitor tolerance could be 5%.

Due to UL and ISO demands above 277 VAC we HAD to use 2 capacitors rated 630 VDC to be sure shoot-through was not possible. Please [see this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357025/how-did-this-capacitor-survive-having-a-nail-driven-through-it/357142) about the capacitor issue and why 2 is much better than one, even for the best grade of capacitors.

You seem to have a keen insight as to how to make reactive sensing or reactive power supplies safe, even during a surge event. By the way, if used at the main service entrance panel you are allowed to use ground as a return path for current, as the neutral to ground strap would be in that panel.For outlets or sub-panels neutral must be the return path.

From our point of view shoot-through meant trusting a single capacitor not to arc internally during a surge, which is why series resistors are mandatory for us. They limit surge currents and turn-on currents if the power is switched on during a cycle peak (90 \$^{o}\$). The resistors protect any down-stream diodes and opto-couplers by limiting peak possible currents to their safe region. A well built reactive power supply is supposed to be safe to short out, as the capacitors set the overall current and resistors limit surge currents. We also used 1 mH inductors to block RF or surges with sharp rise/fall times.

Remember the capacitors are transparent to RF and surges with sharp rise/fall times, so the resistors are an insurance policy that works well. Adding an inductor (as an RF choke) is a cost and space-allowed decision.

Comment: For shoot through current definition I read this - https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/glossary/definitions.mvp/term/Shoot-Through%20Current/gpk/1040 so it basically means shorting the supply?

Comment: From our point of view it meant trusting a single capacitor not to arc internally during a surge, which is why series resistors are mandatory for us. They limit surge currents and turn-on currents if the power is switched on during a cycle peak. The resistors protect any down-stream diodes and opto-couplers by limiting peak possible currents to their safe region. A well built reactive power supply is supposed to be safe to short out, as the capacitors set the overall current and resistors limit surge currents. We also used 1 mH inductors to block RF or surges with sharp rise/fall times.

Comment: Remember the capacitors are transparent to RF and surges with sharp rise/fall times, so the resistors are an insurance policy that works well. Adding an inductor (as an RF choke) is a cost and space-allowed decision.

Comment: I put these comments in the answer so they are not deleted over time.

Comment: It is a single-phase source, and you're right that in reality the phase reference doesn't matter, but in the simulator I wanted it to start at cycle peak to model a surge.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You came up with a good design because you did a good simulation of real-world possibilities.

Comment: I've done something like this simulation back in late 70's safely with isolated DC supplies and polarized plug for 60Hz, It used <1/4mA of 120Vrms and I arranged series R's to be rated for 1kV surge. http://tinyurl.com/yb5l6skg  Interesting how it detects zero voltage crossings which I then XOR's into a pulse to gate 10 power Triacs in sequence with a pulse xfmr http://tinyurl.com/yb5l6skg

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I have no idea how you obtained accurate zero crossings from the circuit you show. Even the Falsted simulation shows the edges far removed from the zero crossing.

Comment: @JackCreasey. No offense Jack / Tony, but if this is a debate it belongs in chat. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Sparky;s answer

Comment: @Sparky: "*I did this most every day for 15 years at a surge manufacture plant.*" So it was you generating all those surges!?

Comment: @Transistor. Maybe a bit overstated. New or modified product lines meant months of testing, including 100 amp fuse testing as well as 20ka surge testing. About 1.6 GW for 2ous.

Comment: Make that 0.4GW. It could put out 5GW but no MOV could  survive that!

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is to detect that AC is present within reasonable limits (what are your limits??), I'd use a peak detector based on your TVS.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgWgjK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown two schematics here, one with a 33V clamp and one with a 96V clamp, just to show options. Obviously you only need to select one of them. The circuit will run under the simulator to see the differences in clamp voltage.

[image]

The signal you get from the opto-isolator will occur at some unknown time between initial conduction of the TVS (with its variable threshold) and the CTR of the opto. However the signal will be symmetrical around the AC input sine wave peak at 90Deg which you wanted to achieve.
There will be some minor fluctuation due to the capacitance of the TVS of course, but this should not concern you for your particular application.

I'd suggest that the [P6KE100CA](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/P6KE33A-1301501.pdf) would be a better choice of TVS, but either would work.

The issue of surge suppression I see as separate to your issue of sensing presence, and you should of course have surge suppression on the AC input. This would typically be a VDR surge suppressor close to your AC input.

Comment: Why remove the capacitors (your resistors now need to dissipate 0.6 and 1W)? And what is the purpose of the two branches - what kind of circuit would the two clamp voltages be fed to?

Comment: The two branches simply allow you to simulate both ….you would only need one of them of course. Getting rid of the capacitors gets rid of the uncertainty of pulse position (phase compared to AC input). You have to also include the power dissipated by the TVS of course, but I don't consider it excessive. In the end it's up to you, but you tried to achieve a 90deg sensing phase shift with capacitors and can see it is ineffective.  At no time did you say absolute low power was the objective. There are ways to achieve very low power sensing, but it's more complicated.

Comment: The circuit is not intended for "90-sensing", simply to sense voltage. The 90 figure is just for the simulator, to start the line voltage at its peak to model a worst-case surge. Other than that, phase (and a few ms of delay) don't matter at all.

Comment: I'm aiming for lower power dissipation while still maintaining simplicity. I'd like to be able to run without a heatsink, or even in a plastic case with poor thermal characteristics, without having to worry.

Comment: @Reinderien Then why use resistors at all in your proposed circuit? You could simply use two (two for safety) 600nF mains rated capacitors and the opto-isolator and get about 14mA RMS or you 300nF for about 7mA RMS. A VDR would protect the input from surges.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the VDR comment; let's take this to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83647/varistor-opto-protection